# Socket programming between two android emulator

Tags: android

I am new in android programming. And recently i am trying to socket programming in android emulator. Basically I want to send and receive data using socket connection through TCP/UDP protocol between two emulator and the two emulator are running on the same PC.

Please give me instruction how to do that and if there is any proven example please give the links.

Thanks to all in advance.

BR,
gsmaker

Answer (score 2):

Good explanation https://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#connecting

Edit: Update for broken link.

Comment: Is this still the correct link? It does not seem to be, can someone up date this?